Solving $\frac{dy}{dx} + \cos( \frac{dy}{dx}) = x$
I'm studying for my Diff Eq exam and I came by an old exam topic as follows.
Find a parametric solution of the equation
$\frac{dy}{dx} + \cos( \frac{dy}{dx}) = x$
I tried to solve $u + \cos u = x$ but couldn't find a good approach to tackle this problem as well. I was thinking of expanding $\cos u$ in a series but it gets too complicated!
I'm stuck and any ideas are welcomed!!

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Hint: you're asked to write $x,,y$ as functions of a common variable, which may as well be $u$ since $x$ is already a function of it. Now use $\frac{dy}{du}=u\frac{dx}{du}$. Just be careful with the integration constant.

Follow the approach of setting the derivative as parameter until the end. So, take into account that $y'=\dfrac{\dot y}{\dot x}$, $\dot y=\dfrac{dy}{du}$, $\dot x=\dfrac{dx}{du}$
$u=y'(x)$
$x=u+\cos(u)$
$\dot x=1-\sin(u)$
$\dfrac{\dot y}{1-\sin(u)}+\cos\left(\dfrac{\dot y}{1-\sin(u)}\right)=u+\cos(u)$. This is true for every $u$, then,
$u=\dfrac{\dot y}{1-\sin(u)}\implies y(u)=\dfrac{u^2}{2}+u\cos(u)-\sin(u)+C$
$$\begin{cases}
y(u)=\dfrac{u^2}{2}+u\cos(u)-\sin(u)+C \\
x(u)=u+\cos(u) \\
\end{cases}
$$
A very well chosen setup for this "trick".

Thank you! If I understand this approach, since $\frac{dy}{du}=u\frac{dx}{du}$, I have to integrate the $dy = u \frac{dx}{du} du$, that is find the $y = \int u (1 - sin(u)) du$

Yes, but with exactly this parametrization for $x$, the one that renders the equation into an identity.

The trick is to assume that the solution can be done in parametric form.
The ode
$$
y'(x) + f(y'(x)) = x
$$
has a solution such that
$$
\cases{x = t + f(t)\\ y = y(t)}
$$
now as $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$ we have
$$
\frac{\dot y}{1+\dot f(t)} + f\left(\frac{\dot y}{1+\dot f(t)}\right) = t + f(t)
$$
so we follow with
$$
\frac{\dot y}{1+\dot f(t)} = t
$$
then
$$
\cases{
x(t) = t + f(t)\\
y(t) = C_0 + \int_0^t\eta\left(1+f'(\eta)\right)d\eta
}
$$
